# Coordination Layout Don't Work With Tab Layout

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio, android-coordinatorlayout, android-tablayout

Good day can you help me correct this one? 
In my activity_main.xml, I used Coordination Layout So that my Appbar will work.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.eccp.projects.ecosavers.ecosavers.activities.eco_detailed_information">

<!--COORDINATOR LAYOUT-->
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar"
            />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tablayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffff"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>
```

And In my First Tab my - Organizations feeds don't work, it stuck and will not me allow to slide up to show up the feeds. But sometimes it will work sliding up but, there is an overlapping of layout. I just include my cardview_items.xml as an overview on how it looks like.

```
<RelativeLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.eccp.projects.ecosavers.ecosavers.activities.eco_detailed_information">

<!--COORDINATOR LAYOUT-->
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp">

            <!--Dummy Value 1-->
            <include
                android:id="@+id/card_item"
                layout="@layout/eco_events_cardview" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/card_item"
                layout="@layout/eco_events_cardview" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

[image]

I really need your help. I'm stuck with this one. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be fairly easy to fix:

1. Remove `ViewPager` from `AppBarLayout`
2. Add `ViewPager` as a sibling to a AppBarLayout and add for it `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` and set `layout_width` & `layout_height` to `match_parent`

So your layout should look like afterwards:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    ....>
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        .....>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            .../>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        .....
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I hope, it helps.